# Как достать то, что находится после span (селекторы html)

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, парсер

Как достать то, что находится после `span`?

Мой парсер делает немного не то

```
def box (film_url,headers):
smth_list = []
session = requests.Session()
request = session.get(film_url, headers = headers)
if request.status_code == 200:
    soup = bs(request.content, 'html.parser')
    divs = soup.select('div.short-info')
    for div in divs:
        years = div.select('span')
        year = years[0].text if years else ''
        smth_list.append(year)
    print(smth_list) 
else:
    print('INSIDE PARSING FAILED')
```

> > > ['КиноПоиск:', 'IMDb:', 'Год:', 'Страна:', 'Жанр:', 'Перевод:', 'Дата выхода:', 'Длительность:', 'Режиссер:', 'В ролях:']

Но вывести я хочу то, что находится после `span`, то-есть сам рейтинг, год, страну и тд.

Для наглядности прикрепляют html код

```
<div class="fright">
<div class="short-info kp"><span>КиноПоиск:</span> 7.3</div>
<div class="short-info imdb"><span>IMDb:</span> 7.2</div>
<div class="short-info"><span>Год:</span> 1998</div>
<div class="short-info"><span>Страна:</span> США</div>
<div class="short-info"><span>Жанр:</span> мелодрама, комедия</div>
<div class="short-info"><span>Перевод:</span> Octopus, TVShows, GoldTeam, 
Журавлев, Одноголосый, ColdFilm, SET</div>
<div class="short-info"><span>Дата выхода:</span> 21 сентября 1998</div>
<div class="short-info"><span>Длительность:</span> 22 мин.</div>
<div class="short-info"><span>Режиссер:</span> Джеймс Берроуз</div>
<div class="short-info"><span>В ролях:</span> Эрик МакКормак, Дебра Мессинг, 
Меган Маллалли, Шон Хейс, Шелли Моррисон, Гарри Конник мл., Ли-Эллин Бейкер, 
Бобби Каннавале, Том Гэллоп, Лесли Джордан</div>
```

Нужно чтобы выводило:

> > > ['1998','США','мелодрама, комедия',...]

Comment: Не выкладывайте текстовую информацию в картинках. Если хотите чтобы Вам помогли не ленитесь хотя бы скопировать пример

Comment: @Wairua извиняюсь, изменил на текст

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from bs4.element import Tag


if __name__ == '__main__':
    html = """<div class="fright">
<div class="short-info kp"><span>КиноПоиск:</span> 7.3</div>
<div class="short-info imdb"><span>IMDb:</span> 7.2</div>
<div class="short-info"><span>Год:</span> 1998</div>
<div class="short-info"><span>Страна:</span> США</div>
<div class="short-info"><span>Жанр:</span> мелодрама, комедия</div>
<div class="short-info"><span>Перевод:</span> Octopus, TVShows, GoldTeam, 
Журавлев, Одноголосый, ColdFilm, SET</div>
<div class="short-info"><span>Дата выхода:</span> 21 сентября 1998</div>
<div class="short-info"><span>Длительность:</span> 22 мин.</div>
<div class="short-info"><span>Режиссер:</span> Джеймс Берроуз</div>
<div class="short-info"><span>В ролях:</span> Эрик МакКормак, Дебра Мессинг, 
Меган Маллалли, Шон Хейс, Шелли Моррисон, Гарри Конник мл., Ли-Эллин Бейкер, 
Бобби Каннавале, Том Гэллоп, Лесли Джордан</div>
"""

    h = Soup(html, 'html.parser').find_all('div', {'class': 'short-info'})

    lst = []

    div: Tag
    for div in h:
        span = div.find_next('span')
        if span:
            span.replace_with('')
        lst.append(div.text.strip())
    print(lst)
```

Comment: Я должен был уточнить, значения после span всегда разные...
Я пытаюсь сделать универсальный парсер, который сможет парсить информацию после span для страниц такого типа

Comment: @Chaddydaddy, Какой результат Вы хотите получить на выходе? Просто если взять просто `div.text` то Вы получите всю строку целиком. К примеру `Дата выхода: 21 сентября 1998`

Comment: @Chaddydaddy, Вам нужна вся информация кроме заключенной в тэг `span`?

Comment: Хочу добиться подобного - ['7.3,'7,2','1998','США','мелодрама, комедия', 'Octopus..........] При учёте того что данные всегда будут разными, то-есть парсер делается не только для этой странички именно с этими данными, надеюсь Вы понимаете о чём я

Comment: да, нужно вывести в списочном типе всё, что находится после тэгов `span`

Comment: @Chaddydaddy, Посмотрите, это то, что Вы хотели?

Comment: да, оно! А возможно ли сделать так, чтобы выводило не все span`ы, а только определённые?

Comment: @Chaddydaddy, Например?

Comment: забудьте, к счастью надобность в подобном отпала - все ссылки сделаны однотипно, с одинаковым количеством span`ов. Ещё раз большое Вам спасибо!